# How to enrich AEM package using a low code no code platform(Mendix or OutSystem)

Tags: aem, outsystems, mendix

The enrichment of AEM package is complex process, one need to be aware of AEM completely. I am looking for a low/no code platform which can import an existing AEM package, enrich it, and export it back to AEM.

I tried with Mendix 9.12.3 and later version, but not able to import AEM package zip file same with Outsystem.